# Image detection with C++ using opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, artificial-intelligence, object-detection

So I have been assigned a project on quite short notice, and given that I have a very small amount of experience with c++ I thought it would be a good idea to ask for some help from the community!

Basically, we have a .png which is an image of a baseball game, and we must use opencv (and its likes) to detect, outline and extract coordinates of the bat, using c++.

So far I have installed opencv onto visual studio 2019 and read through hours and hours of tutorials but feel like I have not made a huge amount of practical progress.

As a beginner, I'm wondering if there is anyone here who could make the path forward a bit more clear for me!

Comment: Image processing and object detection is not a topic which could you learn in a "short time". What progress in object detection did you made, do you understand, what opencv is doing with your images and so on? You didnt say how much progress you made, so we cant decide where you have to go, even that this is even to broad. One tip from me, start prototyping opencv with python. You make faster progress, than handling with opencv AND c++ problems. Then, when your prototype works, try to convert this into c++ (this is the way I usually work)

Comment: Have you read this https://docs.opencv.org/master/db/d28/tutorial_cascade_classifier.html ?

Comment: This question is too broad... However...  Luckily for you the "baseball bat" is among items commonly detected by _"off-the-shelf"_ detectors like yolo. Just google for "opencv yolo baseball bat" and you'll see many tutorials on how to use yolo along with opencv. Once you detect it you can then focus on how to find the outline and its coordinates... Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

Template machine is one of the easy solutions, below is an example for template matching from open cv -

https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/matchmethod_orb_akaze_brisk.cpp

You can do this with many other python library's - 
https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/features_detection/plot_template.html#sphx-glr-download-auto-examples-features-detection-plot-template-py

This will not solve object detection problems in general but will be able to find an object of your interest in many cases, this is one of the quick solutions that I can think of.